# Android - SMS - Backing Up Technique

Tags: android

I'm making an application that will backup all SMS messages.

These are my choices,

1. read every sms message details then store it to the server(one by one).
2. read every sms message details then store it to the server(by batch, like 100sms per batch)

What should be the best way?

On choice 1, the use will wait until the backup is finished.

Answer (score 1):

- Choice n°2 for efficiency: read all SMS not yet backed-up (you can keep your own DB of backed-up messages, for instance an ID + a hash based on the sms content) and sent as big request. Con: you might loose some sms if phone is lost for instance
- Choice n°1 for safety: backup the SMS as soon as it is received. Con: it is less efficient from connection point of view.

So it boils down to what you want to offer to your users. I think not much more code would be required to have both options, so I would simply leave it as a preference settings to the user: "instant backup" or "scheduled backup").

On the first time application is ran, I would anyway send a batch of all existing SMSs, not sending 1 by 1.

Comment: thanks for the answer. how would I know if a specific message has been backed up already?

Comment: Save the sms ids in your application and exclude those in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 will require a very good internet connection and it will take more time to send every message.
Option 2 is more efficient, you need only one connection and one request to the server.

Comment: that is great! if i'll choose option 2, is there any limit on posting data using httppost?

Comment: I think the limit would be on the server and not in httppost.

Comment: Limit is also on the connection reliability: on 3G network, you might want to limit the size of your requests to avoid loosing all you did because there was a connection drop.